# URL parameters in $httpBackend (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to receive an URL parameter in $httpBackend in angularJS? I would like to do something like:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/v1/users/{userId}').respond(function (method, url, data) {
    // somehow read {userId} and act differently depending on what the value is

    return [200];
});
```

Having this functionality would really make it easy to create a rather functional mock API (easier to develop the front-end application without having to run the whole backend).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a regexp instead of a string as the URL. In the callback function, extract the `userId` from the URL, and answer what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Sir.
Should anyone need an exemplary RegExp for that purpose, please consider mine: /^/items/\d$/
Hope it helps, too!